# New to Android: openOrCreateDatabase(): where does the sqlite file go?

Tags: database, android, sqlite

When I call

```
myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Where does the database file get created?

I can't find it anywhere. o_O

Comment: More info: I'm on Ubuntu, working in Eclipse 3.5 with ADT installed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*All databases, SQLite and others, are stored on the device in `/data/data/package_name/databases`.*

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html